# set values for multiple nouislider in meteor

Tags: meteor, nouislider

How do I set multiple instances of the nouislider in Meteor?

I have initialed  multiple sliders on a page like codes in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29503969/initialize-multiple-instances-of-no-ui-slider-in-meteor) . I would like to set the value of sliders synchronized with a collection, but now I am only able to initialized the value with the collection in "start" option.

I've been trying calling a function on 'slide' event. But in the function I find no way to select all the sliders, or use .val().

```
var updateSliders=function(){

   var slider=$(".sliderrr");
   console.log(slider);

   slider.each(function(){
     console.log($(this).val());
  })
};
```

Comment: At http://nouislider.meteor.com/ if you try `$('#slider').val()` in the console, you get the value of the slider.

Answer (score 1):

I will base this answer on what you wrote on github

```
<div class="slider-container"> 
          <div class="sliderrr"></div>
</div>
```

and

```
var slider=$(".sliderrr");
  slider.each(function(){
   console.log("value:",$(this).val());
  })
```

The problem is that you are calling 'each' on the sliderrr instead of the slider-container.

```
Template.body.rendered = function () {
  //init the slider
  this.$('.sliderrr').noUiSlider({
  start: 5,
  connect: "lower",
  step: 0,
  format: wNumb({
    decimals: 0,
  }),
  range: {
    'min': 0,
    'max': 30
  }
  });

  //This is the part I changed
  var sliderino = this.$('.slider-container');
  sliderino.children('.sliderrr').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
  });

};
```